# How to use Windows Live Writer with a SharePoint 2010 wiki?

Tags: wiki

Is there any way to use Windows Live Writer with a SharePoint 2010 wiki?

It should be possible by using the MetaWeblogAPI that hooks into SharePoint 2010, as per
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/MetaWeblogAPI.aspx 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode55NotABlogALocalXMLRPCMetaWebLogEndpointThatLiesToWindowsLiveWriter.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I think that Live Writer still doesn't work with SharePoint Wikis directly. There are some rather unpleasant workarounds in this old thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462/sharepoint-wikis if you want to give them a try.

p.s. I found that with a quick Bing. I knew it was out there somewhere, but still...

Comment: You are right: Live Writer does *not* work with wikis but with SharePoint blogs... Is there any 3rd party that build such an API for wikis?

Comment: I seem to recall that some folks will use Live Writer to publish things to a "dummy blog" and snarf the html to post into wikis.  I know we've talked about that over on Stump the Panel before.